# Win32API - Click Button on Winform Application through Adapter

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, adapter

I need to click on a windows form application button through my adapter using win32Api.

I have found the button on the windows form screen using this code

```
        childHwnd = Win32API.FindWindowByPosition(ptr, new Point(intbtnx, intbtny));
```

Now I need to auto click this button. I am not sure how to do it. Need some help please.

I have written this so far but this only fetches the button i need to click it.

```
     childHwnd = Win32API.FindWindowByPosition(ptr, new Point(intPwdx, intPwdy));
```

Need to click the button that is available in childHwnd

Comment: [This](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/345d85e8-cc5f-4508-b3f2-74ee43521169/how-to-click-a-button-in-another-application-programmatically-in-c?forum=winforms) might be helpfull

Comment: Wrong approach. Use [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/index).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SendMessage` API for this

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, int wParam, int lParam);

private const uint BM_CLICK = 0x00F5;

SendMessage(childHwnd, BM_CLICK, 0, 0);
```

I should note that you will not see the click animation of the button, that only appears when you actually click on it.
It should however perform the code from its click event

**EDIT**
In the comments the OP asks to delay the `SendMessage` with 5 seconds, without freezing the application.
One simple solution is this

from the `Toolbox` in VS drop a `Timer` component on the form.

Set its property `Interval`to `5000`
Set its  property `Enabled` to true
Doubleclick on the event `Tick` and write this code there

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     timer1.Enabled = false; // write this if you only want this to happen once
     SendMessage(childHwnd, BM_CLICK, 0, 0); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
but it is giving me error on this line.

 private const uint BM_CLICK = 0x00F5;

That it should have a return type

Comment: I am not getting that error, can you edit your question and put the exact code there that gives this error

Comment: Why the downvote ? It may be not the best approach, but this does answers the question of the OP

Comment: I did not give the downvote. But i was able to fix the error. I removed private and it worked perfectly. Can you please tell me the logic behind this code?

Comment: There is not much logic here. The SendMessage function will put a `Click` request in the message queue of the button. The button will react by performing its `onClick` event. thats it

Comment: That's not at all what's happening. Sending a [BM_CLICK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/bm-click) message does something very different from what is described in the previous comment. Make sure you read the *"Remarks"* section in the documentation as well. This is an issue you do not have to deal with when doing it right, by using [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/index).

Comment: @IInspectable Actually it is exact what is happening, all be it explained a bit simplyfied. The BM_CLICK puts 2 messages in its messaging queue, WM_LBUTTONDOWN and WM_LBUTTONUP and thus simulates a click. Allthough `UI Automation` would be a better solution, this answers the exact question of the OP.

Comment: I would also like a 5 second pause before the button is clicked how can i achieve that?

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(5000);` just before the SendMessage could do that. It will however freeze your program for 5 seconds to. So best put this in a seperate thread

Comment: I do not want the program to freeze. My application is a simple login page so what i want is user should be able to see the login screen so therefore i want to put a 5 second break before the button is clicked and next page is loaded

Comment: In that case you can simply put a `Timer` on the form, and put the call to SendMessage in its `Tick` event, and set the `Interval` to `5000`