# C# - Finding Coordinates of a Winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application

I have a simple login screen windows form application and I am controlling that application through an adapter now i want to find the coordinates of the textboxes and button, I tried using the coordinates after right clicking the textbox control and picking the location from its property but it did not work. So i want to find the proper location, as windows form application form size can be changed during the run-time. So, how can i find the windows form coordinates.

I have tried using the coordinates provided in the properties of the textbox and button controls but those did not work.

```
IntPtr childHwnd = Win32API.FindWindowByPosition(ptr, new Point(intFirstNameCoordX,intFirstNameCoordY));
```

This is how i want to find the window.

I want to find the textbox and buttons position in windows form. I was googling and found some Spy++ tool but i am not sure if that is what i require and if it is then can anyone please guide me how i can use it to find the position in a simple window form application.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? The (absolute) screen coordinates of some controls, or the relative coordinates of those controls relative to their owning window?

Comment: If you have an application that needs to check another in some way, [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview) is a good choice, IMO. You can be notified when a Window is opened (any Window) and parse the Descendant tree to have informations of any of its child controls. Also, you can performs actions on these controls, if needed.

Comment: @elgonzo I want the absolute coordinates means, even if i change the size of the desktop application even then the coordinates should remain fixed. Which means the coordinates are not dependent on the desktop application size, so they consider the desktop application screen as the actual screen and then give us the fixed x and y coordinates which are not dependent on screen size

Comment: @jimi Can you tell me a bit more about this please? What is it for and how can i use it?

Comment: I am still confused about what you _really_ want. You are talking about an unnamed mysterious adapter. I have no idea what you mean when you are talking about an adapter. You seem to want to use _relative_ coordinates that are _independent_ of the actual size of the window containing the controls. If the coordinates should be independent of the actual application window size, those coordinates cannot be pixel coordinates, no? So, what is the coordinate system you are actually trying to use? I still can't make any sense of it...

Comment: @elgonzo Yes thats correct, i want coordinates that are independent of the actual size of the window containing the controls

Comment: You need to explain what you're trying to achieve; don't describe the tools you decided to use, describe the process. What actions do you want to perform?

Comment: Well, I saw your other question: [Win32API - Click Button on Winform Application through Adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55413606/7444103). You just need to activate the default action of a button. UI Automation is the tool of choice, IMO. You just need to find the child Button control with some description of it (the text, for example) and use an `InvokePatter` on the Button, which will cause the default action of the Button, a click event.

Comment: But, you describe a LogIn Window. Logging into what, exaclty?

Answer (score 3):

OK, I can see that you are using WinApi functions, so I won't go deeper into that, just give you some idea.

First, you can get the main window handle. You can get the handle by process (enum process windows) or by it's caption. If you want to get the handle by caption you can use [FindWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowa)

This handle is the window handle. Next, you can enum it's child windows - for example panels or other controls, using [EnumChildWindows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumchildwindows)

Now the rest depends on your GUI architecture. You may have edits and buttons in panels, so you will have to search for child windows of that panel. You may have controls just put on your main window - so you just search for child controls of that window.

Next, when you find the control, you're interested in, you can get more info, using for example [GetWindowRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowrect)

Comment: So you are saying I should not Find the window by its position rather than its handles? If yes, than where can i find the handle name?
I am so new to this so apologize in advance

Comment: So I got you the functions :) FindWindow - you will find your main application window. Then you have to use EnumChildWindows to find its children. Everything is a window - window, panel, button, textbox... FindWindow will get you handle of your mainWindow. EnumChildWindows will get you handles and some other stuff of children windows.

Comment: Okay i get this but how can i get the handles for the windows? Like do i have to use some tool? Like some tree visualizer or something? Where i know the parent handle, the child handle etc..

Comment: No, handles are different every time the control is created. You will get handles from FindWindow and EnumChildWindows. Read the links in my post :)

Comment: Currently in my code i am finding the MainWindowHandle like this  IntPtr ptr = MainWindowHandle;

Comment: OK, so you have the handle to main window. So use now EnumChildWindows.